# I can't run this python program

Tags: python

I tried running this python program is showing syntax error

```
age=int(input('how old are you?22')
Next_year_age=age+1
print (f'on my next birthday,i will be (next_year_age).')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the error message.

Comment: I'm not a Python developer, but the fact that you have mismatched parentheses on the first line seems like it would be a problem.

Comment: Count your parentheses, you're missing one on the first line. The error message will include the location, so when you ask, include the full error message. It's easy to spot in a three line program, but don't expect people to hunt for a vague "syntax error" in a longer piece of code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please first take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask]. Don't forget to first search for an answer before posting your question. And always include the error message if you get one.

Comment: It looks like several people have suggested how to fix the problem. To find this yourself, you can start on the line that the error message shows. If you don't see any problems with that line, look at the line just before it. Continue working backwards until you find the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
age=int(input('how old are you?')) #First Error -- didnt close ()
Next_year_age=age+1
print (f'on my next birthday,i will be {Next_year_age}.') #Sec Error --use {}
```

Output:

```
how old are you?22
on my next birthday,i will be 23.
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing to close a parenthesis in the first line

```
int(input('how old are you?22'))
```